# Convert web::Json<T> to &mut T

Tags: rust, mutable, actix-web

I am trying to write a simple api to create user in `actix-web` but I need to pass the `User` object as `mutable reference` in the method `db_connector.create_user()` because it needs to be edited behind the scenes - in order to add id, creation-date etc.

```
#[post("/users")]
pub async fn create_user(
    db_connector: web::Data<DBConnector>,
    user: web::Json<User>,
) -> impl Responder {
    match db_connector.create_user(&user.into_inner()).await {
        Ok(_) => HttpResponse::Created().finish(),
        Err(e) => HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(e.to_string()),
    }
}
```

But I am not sure how to convert `web::Json<User>` to `&mut User`. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Could you maybe create a clone of it that you declare as mutable? Like, go `let new_mutable_user: &mut User = user.clone()` if your `User` structure  is cloneable (`#[derive(Clone)]`)?

Comment: Do you really need `&mut User` and not owned `User`? That is, do you need to retain ownership after the call to `create_user`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
#[post("/users")]
pub async fn create_user(
    db_connector: web::Data<DBConnector>,
    web::Json(mut user): web::Json<User>,
) -> impl Responder {
    match db_connector.create_user(&mut user).await {
        Ok(_) => HttpResponse::Created().finish(),
        Err(e) => HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(e.to_string()),
    }
}
```

should work fine, though I didn't test it (and don't know actix).

According to [the documentation](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.Json.html) [`Json`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.Json.html) is

```
pub struct Json<T>(pub T)
```

so it's a trivial wrapper you can pattern match on, and you just need to have a mutable binding in order to create a mutable reference from it.

Alternatively if you want to keep the existing binding style for some reason,

```rust
#[post("/users")]
pub async fn create_user(
    db_connector: web::Data<DBConnector>,
    mut user: web::Json<User>,
) -> impl Responder {
    match db_connector.create_user(&mut user.0).await {
        Ok(_) => HttpResponse::Created().finish(),
        Err(e) => HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(e.to_string()),
    }
}
```

same deal, just without the pattern-based deconstruction of the input Json.

Hell, even just

```rust
#[post("/users")]
pub async fn create_user(
    db_connector: web::Data<DBConnector>,
    user: web::Json<User>,
) -> impl Responder {
    match db_connector.create_user(&mut user.into_inner()).await {
        Ok(_) => HttpResponse::Created().finish(),
        Err(e) => HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(e.to_string()),
    }
}
```

probably works.

Comment: Thanks @Masklinn. The second option works. The other way I found to do the same is `user.into_inner().borrow_mut()`.